# How to upload file in python selenium pytest in Ubuntu os wsl needs double click to upload

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, pytest

had issue running my selenium script, upon running it, it will not click on the file i'm trying to upload, it just stayed on the dialog box and not selecting and clicking the file
[image]

had my code here but its getting an error

```
PATH_FOLDER = get_project_root() + "/file_attachment/"
_elem = browser.find_element(by=By.ID, value="iupload_field")
actionChains = ActionChains(browser)
print("\n path of upload: "+ PATH_FOLDER + "testCert.pdf" )
actionChains.move_to_element(_elem).send_keys(PATH_FOLDER +"testCert.pdf").perform()
```

but its getting an error noSuchElementException

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

any advice or solution is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

   # Wait for the element to be present
   wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
   elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "iupload_field")))

   # Once the element is present, perform the action
   actionChains = ActionChains(browser)
   actionChains.move_to_element(elem).send_keys(PATH_FOLDER + 
   "testCert.pdf").perform()
```

If the above steps do not resolve the issue, please ensure that the element's locator strategy (in this case, using By.ID) is appropriate for locating the element. You may need to use a different locator strategy, such as By.XPATH or By.CSS_SELECTOR, depending on the structure of the HTML.

By following these suggestions, you should be able to address the NoSuchElementException and successfully locate the desired element for file upload.

Comment: tried it using xpath and css_selector but its getting this error selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: [object HTMLInputElement] has no size and location

Comment: Ensure that the element you're trying to interact with is visible on the page. If it's hidden or not displayed, you won't be able to interact with it. You can try using EC.visibility_of_element_located instead of EC.presence_of_element_located to wait for the element to be visible.

Focus: Some elements require focus before you can interact with them. You can try using elem.click() before performing the action with ActionChains to ensure the element has focus.